# Expo Error outputs not showing directories or source

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

Been using react-native with expo. At some point in the project (i.e. it worked when I started the project) the error outputs shift from showing details (specifically the file and/or component names in the code) to replcing the names with (seemingly) random letters.

An example of it working
[Example of working error response from tutorial I follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym5LH.png)

Here are som examples of it not working
[Strange Error response 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9AuX.png)
[Strange Error response 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWqvz.png)

I have been uninstalling and installing some packages (like Ionicons navigations etc). But I cant pinpoint really when this started happening.

Also I use Visual Studio Code

Comment: Ctrl + F write t.navigation in search input. Search every file this way. Then correct this  to navigation / props.navigation or this.props.navigation depending on whether you use class components or hooks

Comment: @kenodek sorry this didnt do anything, there was no result on the search. I dont think it's a problem in the code written by me.